# How can I unlock my Google play account from Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, payment, billing

I want to remove my current credit card from my account but it won't let me, because on Google cloud, I must have a payment method. I don't want to keep using the Google cloud platform.
How can I remove Google cloud from my user account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and should be addressed to vendor support.

Comment: Sorry but this a customer service question. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At GCP, billing account must have a valid payment method at all times. If you are unable to replace a failing payment method with a different, valid payment method, you can [disable billing on your project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#disable_billing_for_a_project).

However, when billing is disabled, your credit card information is retained on your account and GCP is unable to remove it. Credit card information is retained for reporting and auditing purposes only. Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#what_you_should_know_about_removing_a_payment_method).

If you want remove your form of payment from potentially being used on other Google services, such as in your case Google Play Store, you can follow the steps for [Deleting a payment method](https://support.google.com/pay/?visit_id=636750602135748957-2429250943&rd=1#topic=7625285) on Payments.